# How to close the program if a calculation is taking too much time?

Tags: python, discord, sympy

I am making a discord bot and in it, I am trying to implement an integration command. For this, I am using the `sympy` module. However, the `sympy` module is synchronous and would block the program till a calculation is completed which is pretty bad for a bot.

To integrate, I am using the following code:

```py
from sympy import *

x = Symbols("x")
result = integrate(expression) # Expression is user inputed
# Send the result
```

So how do I ensure that if a calculation takes more than say 5 seconds, it should automatically close down? Or is there any better async alternative library that I can use?

Comment: why dont u use multithreading

Comment: This has been answered [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call) I hope it will help you.